# How can I make Android application data persistent?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and am creating a "ToDoList" app in Android.

I used a SQLlite database to save the list in a database table, and 
it saved data perfectly.

I don't have an Android phone, so I can check my application 
only using an emulator.

After saving tasks in the database, if a user restarts the phone then will my task list in database be deleted or not? If it will be deleted then how can I make the data in the table persistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table definitely stays if the user simply reboots the phone. Off the top of my head, I think the only way to get rid of the table completely is to either:

- Delete it (programmatically or via the sql command line)
- Uninstall the application

Simply upgrading your application to a new version will not delete your existing tables (so long as you use the same keystore when making the APK.)

-- Dan

Comment: The database will also get deleted through Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->[App Name]->Clear Data

Comment: Ahh - forgot about that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For saving persistent application data Android offers [various options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

A [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909701/sqllite-or-sharedpreferences-for-persistent-data-storage/4909752#4909752) between SQLite and SharedPreferences for storing persistent data.

Considering you are developing a ToDoList app for Android, I would recommend sticking to SQLite.