# Android SQlite Database Basics

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am implementing a SQlite database into my Android application. I was wondering, if I kill the process of the app on my phone, will the information in the database still be there when I load it up the next time? Or does the database get deleted when you close the app?

Comment: Yes, it will still be there.

Comment: If I were you, I'd simply try it.

Comment: Your DB not be deleted until you delete your APP from the phone. For details how to save data, see the doc here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Android application data persistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629545/how-can-i-make-android-application-data-persistent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is persistent; it will stay on device until it is explicitly deleted.

This question has already been asked and answered here:
[How can I make Android application data persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629545/how-can-i-make-android-application-data-persistent)

I suggest that you also look at this resource for future questions about SQLite databases:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html